# upload a >4mb file to an Azure File Share in 2023

Tags: azure-storage

I need to upload files larger than 4mb to an Azure File Share.

Previously the guidance was to use the [Date Movement Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement#microsoft-azure-storage-data-movement-library-200) The github page implies it's being abandoned / no longer worked on and the v12 libraries should be used instead, but it looks like the 4mb limit is still in place (see [Azure Storage File Shares client library for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Files.Shares/README.md)

What is the current way to upload files >4mb to a file share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum size of a file that can be uploaded in an Azure File Share is 4 TiB ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-range#remarks)).

[image]

When you upload a file in a File Share, you have to upload them in chunks and the maximum size of each chunk can be 4MiB. I think this is where you are getting confused.

[image]

So, to upload a file larger than 4MB, what you would need to do is create an empty file using [`ShareFileClient.CreateAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.shares.sharefileclient.createasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-files-shares-sharefileclient-createasync(system-int64-azure-storage-files-shares-models-sharefilehttpheaders-system-collections-generic-idictionary((system-string-system-string))-azure-storage-files-shares-models-filesmbproperties-system-string-azure-storage-files-shares-models-sharefilerequestconditions-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) method and specify the size of the file there.

Once that is done, you would need to read the source file in chunks (max chunk size would be 4MB) and call [`ShareFileClient.UploadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.shares.sharefileclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-files-shares-sharefileclient-uploadasync(system-io-stream-azure-storage-files-shares-models-sharefileuploadoptions-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) method by passing the stream data read from the source file.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav. I will split the file into chunks. I would have expected the SDK to manage this behind the scenes as it seems a pretty standard requirement. I best get chunking...